# Is there an event which fires when the Layout Details screen is opened?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitecore, sitecore6

I'd like to write some code that fires when the layout details screen is opened. Is there an event, some sort of API or some way to hijack Sitecore UI to allow me to do this? There's nothing in the Sitecore.config events sectiont hat looks relevant.

What I want to do is capture the ID of the item for which I'm currently updating so that I can use it in custom controls later on.

I'm using Sitecore 6.6.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Marek Musielak's answer is great. An alternative would be to change the command fired from the 'Details' Button - Look for `item:setlayoutdetails` in the commands.config.

You could create your own class that does your work then instantiates `Sitecore.Shell.Framework.Commands.SetLayoutDetails` afterwards.

Answer (score 6):

You can override the `\sitecore\shell\Applications\Content Manager\Dialogs\LayoutDetails\LayoutDetails.xml` and change its code beside:

```
<CodeBeside
  Type="Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.Dialogs.LayoutDetails.LayoutDetailsForm,Sitecore.Client"/>
```

to inherit from your custom class that will simply inherits from `LayoutDetailsForm` and overrides e.g. `OnLoad` method.

Comment: This answer was the sort of thing I expected to have to do I ended up using @TwentyGotoTen's answer as it was easier to implement feels like it might be less likely to change in the future. I know Sitecore are rolling out their new UI in version 7.